# JWT Laravel authenthication and middleware

Tags: laravel, vue.js, jwt

I have a web site bult with laravel and vuejs

I have used jwt for login, all works fine

Only the middleware always reyrns false to:

```
//if ($this->auth->check() )
//if ($this->auth->api->check() )

if (Auth::guard('api')->check())            
{
    
    return $next($request);
}
else
{

    return redirect()->to('/admin/index');  
}
```

All these return false and when I refresh I get back to the home page
I have also made the default driver api in config/auth.php but still the check returns false

```
'defaults' => [
    'guard' => 'api',
    'passwords' => 'users',
],



'guards' => [
    'web' => [
        'driver' => 'session',
        'provider' => 'users',
    ],

    'api' => [
        'driver' => 'jwt',
        'provider' => 'users',
    ],
],
```

Regards

Comment: how are you passing the token?

Comment: in authcontroller:
 public function login(Request $request)
 {
  $credentials = request(['email', 'password']);
  $email = $request->email;
  if (! $token = auth('api')->attempt($credentials)) 
  {
   return response()->json(['error' => 'Unauthorized'], 401);
  }
  else
  {
   $user = User::where('email', "$email")->first();
   //dd($user);
   auth('web')->login($user);
   return $this->respondWithToken($token);
  }
 }

Comment: protected function respondWithToken($token)
 {
  
  return response()->json([
  'access_token' => $token,
  'user' => $this->guard()->user(),
  'token_type' => 'bearer',
  'expires_in' => auth('api')->factory()->getTTL() * 60
  ]);
 }

 public function guard()
 {
  return \Auth::Guard('api');
 }

Comment: how are you sending the token with your requests?

Comment: authcontroller.php
public function login(Request $request)
 {
  $credentials = request(['email', 'password']);
  $email = $request->email;
  if (! $token = auth('api')->attempt($credentials)) 
  {
   return response()->json(['error' => 'Unauthorized'], 401);
  }
  else
  {
   $user = User::where('email', "$email")->first();
   //dd($user);
   auth('web')->login($user);
   return $this->respondWithToken($token);
  }
 }

Comment: protected function respondWithToken($token)
 {
  
  return response()->json([
  'access_token' => $token,
  'user' => $this->guard()->user(),
  'token_type' => 'bearer',
  'expires_in' => auth('api')->factory()->getTTL() * 60
  ]);
 }

 public function guard()
 {
  return \Auth::Guard('api');
 }

Comment: I need tp check this in a middleware

Comment: how are you sending the token with the requests to the application?